# Passing Array from Jsp to Controller [Spring MVC]

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass a Javascript array from JSP to My controller class -

JSP -

```
var myArray = [];
myArray .push("OU=Software,DC=example,DC=com,");
myArray .push("OU=IT,DC=example,DC=com,");
$("#ADOus").attr("action","${ctx}/ADSetting?myOUsArray ="+ myArray );
$("#ADOus").submit();
```

Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/ADSetting" },  method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String configureOUs(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("myOUsArray ") String[] myOUsArray ){
        logger.info("myOUsArray.length "+myOUsArray.length);

        return "";
    }
```

The problem is length received is 6 rather than 2. I suppose all the comma separated values are been considered as individual values to array. 
How to resolve this issue, i mean how can the java script array with comma and spaces can be received in my controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the javascript array to JSON using following code.

JSON.stringify(yourArray);

And in controller, accept it as String parameter and then convert it back to array using Jackson library as below:

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String [] array = mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[].class):

Hope it helps!

Comment: Solution is working but is there way around with wrapper classes?